# How can I make my lines not cross with Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is part of my code (not ready yet). I need to make lines of the circles not cross, pretending to be overlaying objects. I'd like not to fill in the blank circles. Thanks in advance!

```
# G7
for i in range (140,0,-20):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.sety(160)
    turtle.setx(i)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.circle(i)

# G8
for i in range (160,0,-20):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.sety(0)
    turtle.setx(i)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.circle(i,180)
```

[image: Python Drawing.jpg]

Comment: Can you attach an image of what you have / what you are trying to do?

Comment: Something like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-X7l9gR22R2uknO-dJqC6qjVXY2f6DSQ/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way seems to be using *fill*:

```
import turtle

turtle.color('black', 'white')
turtle.speed('fastest')

for i in range(140, 0, -20):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setposition(i, 160)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.circle(i)

for i in range(160, 0, -20):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setposition(i, 0)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(i, 180)
    turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

But since you indicate you don't want to use *fill*, another approach is to use *stamping*:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
turtle.color('black', 'white')
turtle.penup()

turtle.sety(140)

for i in range(240, 0, -40):
    turtle.shapesize(i / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.stamp()

turtle.sety(0)

for i in range(280, 0, -40):
    turtle.shapesize(i / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.stamp()

turtle.sety(-10)

turtle.begin_poly()
turtle.circle(10, 180, 12)
turtle.end_poly()

screen.register_shape("semicircle", turtle.get_poly())
turtle.shape("semicircle")

turtle.sety(-160)

for i in range(320, 0, -40):
    turtle.shapesize(i / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.stamp()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

But if neither of those appeals to you, you could simply *draw* the image by calculating where the starting point of each arc is on the circle below it to avoid the overlapping lines.  I.e. do the math.